# How to match a 'word' using regex in django/python

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm using Django/Python and I want to be able to prevent the user from using these words: "login" and "logout" as their username. My current solution is to use a regular expression to check if their input contains the forbidden words (login, logout). If it matters, I'm using a custom `user_model` extended from `AbstractBaseUser`.

```
#models.py
username = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=False, unique=True,
validators=[
validators.RegexValidator(
re.compile('^[^:;\'\"<>!@#$%|\^&\*\(\)~`,.?/=\-\+\\\{\}]? [\w]+$'),
#the line below is my regex for finding the words
re.compile(r'\blogout\b'))],

#variations i've tried are
#re.compile('\bword\b')
#re.compile(r'\b[^word]\b')
#re.compile(r'\Blogout\B')
#re.compile(r"\b(logout)\b")
#re.compile(r'(\bword\b)')
#re.compile('\blogout\b' or '\blogin\b')
#re.compile(r'\b'+'logout'+'\b')
#re.compile(r'^logout\w+$' or r'\blogin\b', re.I)
#re.match(r'\blogout\b','logout') 
#etc...
error_messages={'required':
                    'Please provide a username.',
                    'invalid': 'Alphanumeric characters only',
                    'unique': 'Username is already taken.'},
)
```

I've already read: [Python's how-to Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) unless I missed something but I couldn't find a solution. I also tried but to no avail. My only alternative which I know works, is to implement the validation in the view:

```
#views.py
#login and logout are used by the system so are invalid for usernames
#updated
if clean['username'] == 'login' or 'logout':
   return HttpResponse('Invalid username')
```

But this is not ideal for me.

Comment: Why are you passing it as the second argument of the `RegexValidator` constructor?

Comment: The solution that you said "is not ideal for me" won't even work.  It should be `if clean['username'] in {'login', 'logout'}:`.

Comment: @iCodez that solution worked. However, the error will be shown after the form is submitted. I'll post the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make it a *separate* validator; you are passing the second regular expression into the `RegexValidator()` object as a message.

Just use a simple function that validates the value; you don't need a regular expression here, you want to *invalidate* values instead. Writing a regular expression that matches only on a negative gets complicated and is not what you want to do here:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

forbidden = {'login', 'logout'}

def not_forbidden(value):
    if value in forbidden:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not permitted as a username' % value)


username = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=False, unique=True, validators=[
        validators.RegexValidator(r'^[^:;\'\"<>!@#$%|\^&\*\(\)~`,.?/=\-\+\\\{\}]? [\w]+$'),
        not_forbidden,
    ])
```

See [Writing validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#writing-validators).

Comment: Although i made a minor change, your solution was what i needed. The change i made was to define the 'dict' inside the function: <pre>    def valid_username(invalid_username):
        #login and logout are used by the system so are invalid for usernames
        invalid_usernames = {'login', 'logout'}
        if invalid_username in invalid_usernames:
            raise ValidationError(u'The provided username is already taken.')
</pre>